# whats causing my rdp sessions to disconnect?

Tags: windows, automation, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, freerdp

i have a small scale demo solution where i am automating tasks inside of multiple rdp sessions. I use free rdp to manage these rdp sessions and handle log in. Things have been running smoothly up until recently, when my sessions have started to disconnect themselves before the automation can occur. This issue is occurring on windows server 2016.

Ive browsed through the event viewer and output some logs from freerdp itself, however i cant seem to diagnose the issue here. I have the following logs:

[15:54:33:587] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - recv Set Error Info Data PDU (0x2F), length: 22
[15:54:33:587] [1664:00002618] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - ERRINFO_RPC_INITIATED_DISCONNECT (0x00000001):The disconnection was initiated by an administrative tool on the server in another session.
[15:54:33:657] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.update] - Alternate Secondary Drawing Order [0x0d] Frame Marker
[15:54:33:658] [1664:00002618] [TRACE][com.freerdp.core.update] - BitmapUpdate: 192
[15:54:33:707] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.update] - Alternate Secondary Drawing Order [0x0d] Frame Marker
[15:54:33:764] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - DisconnectProviderUltimatum: reason: 1
[15:54:33:764] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core.rdp] - transport_check_fds() - -1
[15:54:33:764] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.core] - rdp_check_fds() - -1
[15:54:33:764] [1664:00002618] [ERROR][com.freerdp.client.windows] - Failed to check FreeRDP file descriptor
[15:54:33:768] [1664:000000b4] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.channels.rdpsnd.client] - Device already closed
[15:54:33:783] [1664:00002618] [DEBUG][com.freerdp.client.windows] - Main thread exited with 65537

and this more telling message:

[15:54:33:587] [1664:00002618] [INFO][com.freerdp.core] - ERRINFO_RPC_INITIATED_DISCONNECT (0x00000001):The disconnection was initiated by an administrative tool on the server in another session.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!